# responsive image using the after selector

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm wondering if I can make a image inserted with `:after` responsive.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3 swap-bot main-sidebar sidebar">
    <ul id="shop-sidebar">
       <li id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">
          <h2 class="widgettitle">shop powered by </h2>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar>ul>li {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.sidebar .widgettitle {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 15px 15px 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa !important;
}

#text-2 h2:after{
    content: url('https://blabla.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/small.png');
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}
```

I also tried to add `max-width:100%; height:auto;` but it doesn't work either.

Can you point me in right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to set background-image instead of content: url('https://blabla.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/small.png');

Comment: use @media screen and (max-width: 300px) - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I'm very curious as to what situation a `h2` element would ever be part of a list...

Comment: It doesn't do the same thing. Using content, I'm adding a image, I don't set it as background. I don't want a bg image

Comment: @JamesDonnelly in a sidebar

Comment: @MarianIoan What does that matter? Why does it need to be wrapped in a `li` element? Semantically a heading isn't part of a list (unless it's a list of paragraphs with headings, but then I'd argue that a list isn't the best option there either). Your markup should probably look something like: `<div class="sidebar"> <h2>...</h2> <ul>...</ul> </div>`